# How to save user profile info during the first login using AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm learning how to implement AzureAD sign-in. I've created a sample Blazor project with Azure AD authentication (by Visual Studio template). I would like to understand how can I read some user info (name and surname) after the first login and save it.

I've noticed that the project template doesn't use ASP.NET Core Identity. This could be fine because I want to sign-in with my work account.

This is the startup.cs code relative to AzureAD

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

it seems that anything will be called after the user login. 
What I would like to implement is a redirect to somewhere (controller/blazor page) where I can check if I've already saved this user or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to [customize the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-user).

In the `CreateUserAsync` method you could do check to see if the user exists in your data store, and if not, add them.

For server side, I have also used `OpenIdConnect` to respond to post authorization events.

```
services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    Configuration.Bind("OpenIdConnect", options);
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
            {
                // Do some stuff here
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution. Anyway, this solution should work even for Blazor Server Side, right?

Comment: @LeonardoLurci updated my response to show what I have done in the past for server side.

Comment: @mattruma When the CreateUserAsync is called? Every time the user completes login or on every page reload?